# Which energy is in Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

[Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) has the form
$$ p_i={1\over{Z}} e^{-\beta E_i}  $$
for the probability of a system to be in the state $E_i$. $E_i$ is the total energy of the system. For example if in $i$th state all the particles have the same energy $\epsilon$, than $E_i=N\epsilon$, where $N$ is the total number of particles in the system as I've understood from [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/one.pdf) notes.

On the other hand the same formula is [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) for the probaility of finding the single particle of the system in the state $\epsilon_i$

$$ p'_i={{N_i}\over{N}}={1\over{Z}} e^{-\beta \epsilon_i} . $$

Are both of these statements correct?
Dont they contradict one another? I also find it confusing that in the Wikipedia article both system and particle states are labeled by the same symbol.

Answer (score 4):

As Seth pointed out, $$P_i=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_i}$$ is the probability of a single particle to be in the state $i$. The state $i$ has energy $E_i$. The prefactor $\frac{1}{Z}$ is only a normalization constant for the probability -- it insures that $$\sum_{\textrm{all states $i$}} P_i = 1$$ in the discrete probability case. Just insert the upper formula here and we get
\begin{align}
1 &= \sum_{\textrm{all states $i$}} P_i = \sum_{\textrm{all states $i$}}  \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_i} = \frac{1}{Z} \sum_{\textrm{all states $i$}}  e^{-\beta E_i} \\
\Rightarrow Z &= \sum_{\textrm{all states $i$}}  e^{-\beta E_i} 
\end{align}
Hence, by using the notation $N_i = e^{-\beta E_i}$ and $N = N_{tot} = \sum_{\textrm{all states $i$}} N_i = Z$ we get
$$P_i = \frac{N_i}{N}$$
which has a intuitive interpretation as a probability. Note that here $N$ is the number of states and not the number of particles.

Now, if we take $N$ *independent* particles, then  $$P_{tot} = P_{i_1} \cdot P_{i_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot P_{i_N} = \prod_{n=1}^N P_{i_n}$$ is the probability that the first particle is in state $i_1$, the second particle is in state $i_2$, ... If all the particles are in the state $j$, then this formula simplifies to $P_{tot} = (P_j)^N = \frac{1}{Z^N}e^{-\beta N E_j}$.

Comment: How can $E_i$ be probability of single particle to be in the state $i$, when it is explicitly said that it is the probability of the system to be in state $i$ ?

Comment: Don't get your comment. Therefore, once again: $E_i$ is the energy of the $i$-th state and $P_i$ is the probability a particle occupies this state. $P_i$ is a function of $E_i$.

Comment: State of the particle  or of the system ?

Answer (score 3):

Seth and Semoi said the right thing but I would like to make some clarifications.

The Boltzmann (or Gibbs, or canonical) distribution describes ANY subsystem if it is:

- quasi-isolated,
- in the equilibrium with its surroundings.

This subsystem could be a single particle as well as the huge volume containing large amount of particles. For a single particle we usually talk about the ideal gas as in the ideal gas particles are far away from each other and don't interact.

Any quasi-isolated subsystem in the equilibrium has stationary states and so it has an energy spectrum labeled by $E_i$. The probability of system to be found with an energy $E_i$ is distributed according to the canonical distribution

$$p_i = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_i}\tag{1}$$

Suppose you have two quasi-isolated subsystems in the equilibrium $A$ and $B$. Each of them has their own energy spectrum $E_i^{(A)}$ and $E_i^{(B)}$ with distributions $p_i^{(A)}$ and $p_i^{(B)}$ both of the form (1). As $A$ and $B$ are quasi-isolated their joint energy spectrum is just the sum $E_i^{(A)}+E_j^{(B)}$ for all $i$ and $j$ and the joint distribution is the product of $p_i^{(A)}$ and $p_i^{(B)}$ which again has the form of (1). From here we can see that it doesn't matter how small the subsystem is while we are able to describe it as quasi-isolated.

Note, that the canonical distribution could also describe the isolated system if it is huge enough that the big part of it is quasi-isolated.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula $p_i=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_i}$,$E_i$ is not the total energy of the system. It is the energy of a state $i$ which has a probability of occurrence is $p_i$. So in your case, $p_i=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta \epsilon}$.

Comment: What is "state" ?

Comment: state is here same as energy state/level where the particles have same energy.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Both of the statements can be correct. $E_i$ in Boltzmann distribution can both mean the total system energy and the energy of a single particle in the system.

Long answer: Two common situations in which the Boltzmann distribution occur are:

- Microcanonical ensemble: The total system energy $E$ is fixed. One commonly tries to find a distribution over the possible particle states, each state having energy $\epsilon_i$, making sure that $\sum_i^N N_i\epsilon_i = E$ where $N_i$ is the number of particles having energy $\epsilon_i$.
  Note: If we instead were interested in the distribution over microstates, then by the *Fundamental postulate of statistical mechanics*, the probability of each microstate is equal.
- Canonical ensemble: The total system energy is not fixed. One commonly tries to find a distribution over the possible microstates, each having a total system energy of $E_i$. The expected value for the total system energy is then $\sum_i^kp_iE_i = \langle E\rangle$ where the sum is over all microstates.